# HTML Ajax form not working with FormSubmit co API

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, svelte, svelte-3

I'm using Svelte and Astro. And I'm using formsubmit.co for the API to send the email. But it doesn't send the email.

Here is the js

```
<script>
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';
    import jq from 'jquery';

    onMount(() => {
        window.jq = jq;
        jq("#form").submit(function (event) {
            var formData = {
                name: jq("#name").val(),
                email: jq("#email").val(),
                message: jq("#message").val(),
            };

            jq.ajax({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'https://formsubmit.co/ajax/01e95b7b608117ff23368c8ea240889d',
                dataType: 'json',
                accepts: 'application/json',
                data: formData,
                success: (data) => console.log(data),
                error: (err) => console.log(err)
            }); 
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here is the form html

```
<form method="POST">
   <div class="flex">
        <input class="input-style" id="name" type="text" name="name" required placeholder="Name">
        <input class="input-style" id="email" type="email" name="email" required placeholder="Email"> 
         <input type="hidden" name="_subject" value="Downlu - Support Email">
    </div>
    <textarea class="input-style" id="message" name="message" type="message" cols="60" rows="4" placeholder="Message" required></textarea>
     <button class="btn-submit" type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

It just reloads the page, and I've checked my email and nothing shows up.

Comment: I tried a little test with different code and got `This form needs Activation. We've sent you an email containing an 'Activate Form' link. Just click it and your form will be actived!` as a response. You should prevent the form from being submitted in the regular fashion before the ajax function is called - `event.preventDefault()` etc

Comment: Do not mix DOM querying with Svelte. Use `bind:this` to access elements and `on:<event>` for event handling. The shown code does not use Svelte at all...